# How to set customer custom attribute in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I have created some custom attributes for a customer in magento2 community edition,

I have used below code to set in my custom code

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor;

class CreateCustomer extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
 {
  protected $customerRepository;
  protected $accountManagement;
  protected $customerExtractor;

  public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
    CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
  ) {
    $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
    $this->customerExtractor = $customerExtractor;
   parent::__construct($context);
}
  public function execute()
{
  try {
       $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $this->_request);
        $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');
        $confirmation = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password_confirmation');

        $customer = $this->accountManagement
            ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);

         $this->customerRepository = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface::class
        );  

        $customer->setCustomAttribute('is_checked', 0);
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);    
 }catch (StateException $e) {
      print_r($e->getMessage());
   }
  }
}
 $customer->setCustomAttribute('is_checked', 0);
```

This attribute is a custom attribute and I have set default_value as 0, but it is not saving on creating a customer. I can't see any value in the table for any of the customers.

This is not storing in the table. What is the reason please anyone helps me with this.

Here is the screenshot for the attribute in the table

[image]

attribute_code is customer_activated.

Comment: when you are storing that value are u using observer or with in controller ?

Comment: I am using that code in controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that code to save custom attribute of customer

```
$customerRepository = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$customerId = $params['customerId'];
$customer = $customerRepository->getById($customerId);
 
$customer->setCustomAttribute("is_checked",'0');
 
$customerRepository->save($customer);
```

Comment: is_checked is customer custom attribute of backend_type is int in the table

Comment: I am also using same code Ansar, used within quotes and checked, its same again

Comment: how to set custom address attribute value? I created multi select attribute, value s not getting saved

Answer (score 0):

Use setData to save the values, as try like this

```
$customer->setData(array('is_checked'=>0));
```

And use the try catch method for the save function to find possible exceptions.

Also please post the custom attribute creation code

Comment: can we use setData for custom attributes?

Comment: Yes, Did you try this method?

Comment: yes , i am getting error like below
 Exception message: Warning: Missing argument 2 for Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject::setData()

Comment: try like this $customer->setData('is_checked',0);

Comment: same again after using this code also.

Comment: Please post the entire code block, will have more idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82344/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rinto-george).